# XML DOM get child best and fast way

Tags: php, xml

I have a nested xml from an external server like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <ResponseDetails Language="en">
      <SearchHotelPriceResponse>
        <HotelDetails>
          <Hotel HasExtraInfo="true" HasMap="true" HasPictures="true"
    Recommended = "true">
             <City Code="AMS"><![CDATA[ Amsterdam ]]></City>
             <Item Code="AME"><![CDATA[ AMERICAN ]]></Item>
          </Hotel>
          <Hotel HasExtraInfo="true" HasMap="true" HasPictures="true"
    Recommended = "true">
             <City Code="AMS"><![CDATA[ Amsterdam ]]></City>
             <Item Code="AME"><![CDATA[ AMERICAN2 ]]></Item>
          </Hotel>
       </HotelDetails>
     </SearchHotelPriceResponse>
    </ResponseDetails>
</Response>
```

COnsider that I can have many other level inside hotel, but the first goal is to take the `Item` value

I have tried in this way:

```
$hotelNodes = $xml_en->getElementsByTagName('Hotel');
foreach($hotelNodes as $hotel) {
    //how to print item value?!
}
```

I have to make another `getElementsByTagName` or is possible to take this with soemthing like `$hotel->getElementsByTagName('Item')->nodeValue` or something like this?

Comment: why not xpath? `//Hotel/Item` will get all item tags that are children of Hotel tags.

Comment: I can try with it, can you please make an answer to understand well xpath with my problem? Because my goal is to store into an array some value inside node Hotel @MarcB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
        $hotelNodes = $xml->getElementsByTagName('Hotel');
        foreach($hotelNodes as $hotel) {
            $nameofitem = $hotel->getElementsByTagName( "Item" );
            $nameofcity = $hotel->getElementsByTagName( "City" );
            echo('<p>name hotel: '.$nameofitem->item(0)->nodeValue.' name city: '.$nameofcity->item(0)->nodeValue.'</p>');
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($xml_en);
$items = $xp->query('//Hotel/Item');
foreach($items as $item) {
   echo $item->nodeValue;
}
```

Comment: yes but I need to do this with more child node like Item, for each of this I have to do a foreach, Is possible to have only one foreach??